# How to using amq.topic to pub/sub messages in Apache Qpid

Tags: jms, amqp, qpid

I have a C++ publisher to send messages like this:

```
Connection connection;
connection.open("127.0.0.1", 5672);
Session session = connection.createSession();
Message msg;
msg.setData("TestAMsg");
msg.getDeliveryProperties().setRoutingKey("test.A");
session.messageTransfer(arg::content = message, 
                         arg::destination = "amq.topic");
msg.setData("TestBMsg");
msg.getDeliveryProperties().setRoutingKey("test.B");
session.messageTransfer(arg::content = message, 
                         arg::destination = "amq.topic");
```

And I have a Java subscriber like this:

```
AMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new 
                AMQConnectionFactory("amqp://guest:guest@myhost/test?
                                     brokerlist='tcp://127.0.0.1:5672'");
AMQConnection connection = (AMQConnection) 
                             connectionFactory.createConnection();
org.apache.qpid.jms.Session session = connection.createSession(false, 
                                             Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
AMQTopic destination = (AMQTopic) 
        AMQDestination.createDestination("topic://amq.topic//exclusive='false'?
                                          bindingkey='Test.A'");
MessageConsumer messageAConsumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
Message message_ = messageConsumer_.receive();
```

No messages received in above code. I am very confused how this will work? What is the right  form of bingding URL for consumers? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Your consumer specifies a binding key that is different than the routing key used by the producer.

Your producer code:

```
msg.getDeliveryProperties().setRoutingKey("test.A");
```

Your consumer code:

```
AMQTopic destination = (AMQTopic) 
        AMQDestination.createDestination("topic://amq.topic//exclusive='false'?
                                          bindingkey='Test.A'");
```

Notice the difference in case for the first character of each key. Your producer uses `test.A` and your consumer uses `Test.A`, and since the keys are case-sensitive they are considered completely different. That's why your producer won't get any messages.

Answer (score 0):

your binding key should be test.# or test.*

the differencees between # and *, follow this link http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/2/html/Messaging_User_Guide/chap-Messaging_User_Guide-Exchanges.html#sect-Messaging_User_Guide-Exchange_Types-Topic_Exchange

Comment: You can also use an exact match for a binding key, see @Brian Kelly answer